# Access freemaker variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

I need to access freemaker variables in jquery file. Currently I am accessing as code below. However due to Content Security Policy I can not write inline JavaScript in ftl file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var emp_id = '${emp_id}';
</script>
```

I can use input type hidden and pass the ftl variable value to hidden object and then access it as below.

```
<input id="emp_id" type="hidden" value='${emp_id}'/>
```

However I have some jquery objects in different ftl files which populates multiple attributes from freemaker but it does not seem good logic to create 30 hidden type input fields. One code sample given below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var globalobj= {
        dept: '${dept}',
        finyear: '${finyear}',
        role : '${role}',
        .........,.....
};
</script>
```

I tried moving this code to a js file and add reference to that js in ftl file. However it does not work.
Is there any other way to do it?